# How do I use comma-separated-values received from a URL query in Objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I use comma-separated-values received from a URL query in Objective-c?
when I query the URL I get csv such as ("OMRUAH=X",20.741,"3/16/2010","1:52pm",20.7226,20.7594).
How do I capture and use this for my application?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Use a CSV parser: http://freshmeat.net/projects/ccsvparse

Or parse the data yourself into an array:

```
// myString is an NSString object containing your data
NSArray *array = [myString componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
```

Comment: I don't see how a JSON parser is relevant for parsing CSV data.

Comment: I mistook the ( brackets for [. If they were [ then the string would be a valid JavaScript array and thus parsable by a JSON parser

Comment: Thanks pheelicks, apparently my problem is creating/initializing that NSString object in the first place.
An example is this link "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GBPEUR=X&f=sl1d1t1ba&e=.csv", which returns csv. I dont know how to capture this as an object since I cannot use an NSXMLParser object.

Answer (score 0):

I recently dealt with CSV parsing for Yahoo! Finance as well. I used [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) to write a parser in C that was good enough for the CSV I was getting. It handled everything but escaped quotes, which are not going to show up much in stock quotes. It was pretty painless and a good learning experience. I'd post the code, but it was work-for-hire, so I don't own it.

Turning a C string into an `NSString` is easy. If you have it as an `NSData`, as you likely do at the end of a URL download, just do `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:csvData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`. If you have a pointer to a character buffer instead, use `[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:buflen encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`. `buflen` could be `strlen(buffer)` if `buffer` is a normal, NUL-terminated C string.